# Quais os tipos de banco de dados podem ser aplicados em um app mobile utilizando apache cordova?

Tags: apache-cordova, mobile

Gostaria de saber se é possível construir apps mobile com banco de dados utilizando o apache Cordova, e se é possível também fazer integração com um banco em um outro local, tipo um banco de dados externo que fica enviando dados para o app (nada demais, igual a maioria dos apps). Não sei se é possível. Pesquisei e não encontrei nenhum material. Alguém pode me informar se é possível e como? Ou possa indicar algum material (pode ser inglês).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dando uma pesquisada, encontrei essa página aqui, sobre um banco local:

- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html
- http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/

Do primeiro link:

> "*This API is based on the W3C Web SQL Database Specification and W3C
>   Web Storage API Specification. Some devices already provide an
>   implementation of this spec. For those devices, the built-in support
>   is used instead of replacing it with Cordova's implementation. For
>   devices that don't have storage support, Cordova's implementation
>   should be compatible with the W3C specification.*
>
> Essa API é baseada na Especificação de Banco de dados SQL da WEB, da
>   W3C e na Especificação da API de Armazenamento WEB. Alguns
>   dispositivos já provêem uma implementação delas. Para esse caso, o
>   recurso do aparelho é utilizado em vez da implementação do Córdova.
>   Para aparelhos sem suporte à "persistência", a implementação do
>   Córdova deve ser compatível com a especificação da W3C.

Quanto à fazer os envios pro banco remoto, você poderia, por exemplo trabalhar com requisições simples, lembrando AJAX da vida e, usando a linguagem que recebe elas no server remoto, salvar isso no banco de dados.

Aqui um tópico dos nossos irmãos do Stack gringo:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263578/ajax-request-from-phonegap-android-fails
- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: Se tiver algum exemplo simples de utilização de aplicação com Cordova utilizando BD, por favor me passe. Obrigado pela resposta.